# Pickle Key error "Y" using socket

Tags: python, sockets, pickle

I am trying to send a dictionary to my client and it is fin on the server end but when it gets to unpickling the dictionary it comes up with error `KeyError: 'Y'`.

Why?

Here is my code:

client.py:

```
import socket, pickle

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost", 10000))

def userDump():
    s.sendall("userdump")
    d = s.recv(1024)
    return pickle.loads(d)

print userDump()

s.close()
```

server.py:

```
import pickle, socket
s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
address = 'localhost'
port = 10000
s.bind((address, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    c, clientaddress = s.accept()
    c.send("You're Connected")
    d = c.recv(1024)
    if d == "userdump":
        u = {"hello":"hi", "hi":"hello"}
        print u
        c.send(pickle.dumps(u))

    c.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `userDump()` should be corrected as:

```
def userDump():

    d = s.recv(1024)
    s.sendall("userdump")
    d = s.recv(1024)    
    return pickle.loads(d)
```

In your code you receive `"You're Connected"` in `d` and you are trying to unpickle it.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly doesn't help that the "You're connected" message is being concatenated with the pickle in your client. Removing that `send` from the server code appears to make your program work correctly.

Comment: In case the answer isn't obvious, the "Y" at the beginning of the message is being looked up by the `pickle.loads` function in a dictionary of pickle field types, and there is no "type 'Y'" field.

Answer (score -1):

The pickle protocol is version dependent. Could it be that you use different Python / pickle versions on client and server? In that case select a low protocol version explicitly as explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html).

Alternatively use JSON or something called [Pyro](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4)

(O, and, indeed, first make the correction suggested by holdenweb...)

Comment: Ok to downvote if you want, but how can a reader with just the info Jonah provided be so sure the same protocol version is used on client and server? Compound mistakes happen...